# Limit of $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{ (x +x^2+x^3+ \cdots +x^n)-n}{x-1}$

Tags: limits, factorial

What is the limit of 
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1}   \frac{ (x +x^2+x^3+ \cdots +x^n)-n}{x-1}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: distribute n into n ones, give one to each power of x.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use l'Hospital's rule. You will also need to know how to sum up the first $n$ positive integers.

Edit: Here is some more detail if you need it. $$\lim_{x\to 1}(x+x^2+\cdots+x^n-n)=n-n=0$$
And $$\lim_{x\to 1} (x-1)=0.$$
So we may use l'Hospital's rule to show that your limit is the same as the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 1}(1+2x+\cdots+nx^{n-1}).$$
Can you see how to finish from here?

Comment: I checked, this answer fits perfectly as a comment. Unless you want to provide more details.

Comment: @rtybase Hopefully that's enough now without completely giving away the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $1$ is a root of the numerator of this fraction, meaning $(x-1)$ will cleanly divide it.  Using polynomial long division, you'll find:

$$\frac{x^n + x^{n-1} + \cdots + x - n}{x-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^{n-k}$$

And you can now find the limit by plugging in $x=1$: no more division-by-zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's has two ways: first by taking Hopital : because by setting $x=1$ we have $\frac{0}{0}$ for this fraction: Now I take Hopital( taking derivative of numerator and denominator separately):

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x+x^2+...+x^n-n}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1+2x+3x^2...+nx^{n-1}}{1}$$
now by setting $x=1$ we have:

$$Limit=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

In second method, I use geometric series for summing numerator.

$$x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}$$

Now replace this in main limitation:

$$=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}-n}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n+1}-(n+1)x+n}{(x-1)^2}$$

No by setting x=1: we have $\frac{0}{0}$ for this limit and I take Hopital double times for resolving this matter.

first Hopital:
$$=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(n+1)x^{n}-(n+1)}{2(x-1)}$$

first Hopital:
$$=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{n(n+1)x^{n-1}}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

***Notice:*** because we have ${x \to 1} $ so I could not use $\frac{a}{1-q}$ for calculating sumation of geometric series.